# DynamoDB - Read/Write Capacity Alarms using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, cloudwatch-alarms

Im trying to create a cloudwatch alarm for dynamodb read capacity units

This is my code, I have given threshold as "4", but in the console the threshold value is "0.07"

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "consumed_read_units" {
  alarm_name                = "dynamodb_${var.dynamodb_table_name}_consumed_read_units"
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = "5"
  metric_name               = "ConsumedReadCapacityUnits"
  namespace                 = "AWS/DynamoDB"
  period                    = "60"
  statistic                 = "Average"
  dimensions =  {
    TableName = "${var.dynamodb_table_name}"
  }
  threshold                 = 4
  alarm_description         = "This metric monitors DynamoDB ConsumedReadCapacityUnits for ${var.dynamodb_table_name}"
  insufficient_data_actions = []
}
```

[image]

Is there any calculations for entering the threshold values?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the threshold parameter in the above cloudwatch metric alarm is in units/minute, instead of units/second. So with threshold=4, if we convert threshold in units/second it comes out to be .07(after rounding off). So, you should use threshold value of 240 units/minute [in terraform] = 4 units/second [in aws dashboard]

Comment: Hello...
Inspect // Watch ...
Your answer, in addition to being considered a comment. It is poorly done.
It is useful to insert an effective response, with codes and references. Concluding a practical and efficient solution.
This platform is not just any forum. We are the largest help and support center for other programmers and developers in the world. Review the terms of the community and learn how to post.